# My java program is getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

When my program enters this part of my code it gets a runtime error.First off I know its not indented at all.I forgot to do that so I know it is a pain to read.This method is passed 7 array lists,two of which are my own classes I made.

```
public static void leaderboards(ArrayList<String> teamName, ArrayList<Outcome> aOutcome, ArrayList<Fixture> aFixture, ArrayList<Integer> awayScore, ArrayList<Integer> homeScore, ArrayList<Integer> awayNum, ArrayList<Integer> homeNum) {
    int tem, temps;
    ArrayList<Leaderboard> aLeaderboard = new ArrayList<Leaderboard>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < teamName.size(); counter++) {
        Leaderboard aLeaderboardEntry = new Leaderboard();
        aLeaderboard.add(aLeaderboardEntry);
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aOutcome.size(); counter++) {
        tem = (aFixture.get(counter)).getHomeNumber();
        temps = (aFixture.get(counter)).getAwayNumber();
        (aLeaderboard.get(tem - 1)).setGamesPlayed();
        (aLeaderboard.get(temps - 1)).setGamesPlayed();
    }
    ArrayList<Results> aResult = new ArrayList<Results>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aOutcome.size(); counter++) {
        Results aResultsEntry = new Results();
        aResult.add(aResultsEntry);
        (aResult.get(counter)).setFixtureNumber(counter + 1);
        (aResult.get(counter)).setHomeNumber(homeNum.get(counter));
        (aResult.get(counter)).setAwayNumber(awayNum.get(counter));
        (aResult.get(counter)).setHomeScore(homeScore.get(counter));
        (aResult.get(counter)).setAwayScore(awayScore.get(counter));
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aResult.size(); counter++) {
        if (((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeScore()) > ((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayScore())) {
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).sethomeWins();
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).setTotalPoints(3);
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setawayLosses();
        } else if (((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeScore()) == ((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayScore())) {
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).sethomeDraws();
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).setTotalPoints(1);
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setawayDraws();
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setTotalPoints(1);
        } else if (((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeScore()) < ((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayScore())) {
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).setHomeLosses();
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setawayWins();
            (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setTotalPoints(3);
        }
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aResult.size(); counter++) {
        (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).setHomeGoalsFor((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeScore());
        (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeNumber())).setHomeGoalsAgainst((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayScore());
        (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setAwayGoalsFor((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayScore());
        (aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setAwayGoalsAgainst((aResult.get(counter)).getHomeScore());
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aLeaderboard.size(); counter++) {
        int goalsFor = (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeGoalsFor() + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getAwayGoalsFor();
        int goalsAgainst = (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeGoalsAgainst() + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getAwayGoalsAgainst();
        int goalDifference = goalsFor - goalsAgainst;
        (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).setGoalsDifference(goalDifference);
    }
    System.out.println("     Positon     Team     Games Played    Home Wins   Home Draws   Home Losses  Home Goals For   Home Goals Against   Away Wins   Away Draws  Away Losses  Away Goals For    Away Goals Against   Goal Difference    Total Points");
}

for(int counter = 0; counter<teamName.size();counter++) {
    System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " + teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
    System.out.print((aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeLosses());
    System.out.println();
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
(aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber())).setawayWins();
```

If ye need any other parts of the code such as the classes themselves just ask
This is the error it produces

```
> D:\>java Project4 Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20
>         at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>         at Project4.leaderboards(Project4.java:198)
>         at Project4.main(Project4.java:114)
> 
> D:\>
```

Edit:
Away wins is an int declared in The Leaderboards class

```
public int awayWins;
```

Set away wins is this method

```
public void setawayWins()
  {
  awayWins++;
  }
```

Comment: *"First off I know its not indented at all.I forgot to do that so I know it is a pain to read"* If you can't be bothered to fix it, why should anyone else be bothered to try to help you?

Comment: post the declaration of `setawayWins`

Comment: aLeaderboard size is not equal to aResult.size(). the for loop counter is looping on aResult.size(). the line aLeaderboard.get((aResult.get(counter)) is trying to access which is not there.

Comment: I have posted the declaration of setawayWins

Comment: I know aLeaderboard size is not equal to aResult size.aLeaderboard should be 20 where as aResult should be 270.

Comment: That is why it is throwing error. Also you way of adding an object to arraylist and then trying to access it via counter to set the values is very strange. I dont get the practice behind that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably with `(aResult.get(counter)).getAwayNumber()`. It has a value of 20 and the aLeaderboard list does not have that index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to retrieve out of margin element from the ArrayList *"aLeaderboard"*

for a example-

> Your arraylist consist with 5 element {0,1,2,3,4}, You are going to retrieve 6th element from the arraylist.

Unfortunately i cant give a solution due to un-clearness of yo following vars

- aLeaderboard
- aResult
- getAwayNumber
- setawayWins